# How to record PID and its command every 15s?

Tags: linux, process, ps, top, htop

For troubleshooting purpose, I'd like to record PID and its command every 15s and write them to a text file.

The desired output:
TimeStamp, PID, Command

Answer (score 1):

This will get you you the three columns you want:

```
$ ps -hopid,comm | perl -anle'print time, ", $F[0], $F[1]"'
1541626566, 6496, gedit
1541626566, 7513, bash
```

You can limit or extend the scope of `ps`, ie. what processes it lists. Then you put this in a loop with redirection.

```
while true; do echo x; sleep 15; done > out
```

Replace `echo x` with the command proper and `out` with the file name you choose.

As for the command producing the information, here's a run-down.

- `ps -hopid,comm` - `ps` is obvious, `-h` turns off the header line and `-o` stands for the output (PID and command).
- This goes to the Perl command, namely `perl -anle'print time, ", $F[0], $F[1]"'`. Here `perl` is Perl. The `-anle` flags reprent correspondingly: `a` - load input into an array, `n` - take care of new lines, `l` - process each single line, and finally `e` - execute the code that follows.
- And now the code follows: `'print time, ", $F[0], $F[1]"'`. First print the time stamp, then the first column of the array that holds the input material, and then the second.